# Application requires version 4.0 full or other compatible .Net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks, one-click-web-publishing

I am getting error Application requires version 4.0 full or other compatible .Net framework

I have the below mentioned prerequisite-

Windows Installer 4.5

Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)

SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2

SQL Server 2008 Express

Windows Installer 3.1

Please let me know why is throwing such error when i have mentioned Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Full version, not just the client profile. Installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 should also satisfy this requirement.